# What is this type of graphics application called?

Tags: software-recommendation

I want to make a picture where I have a lot of image elements that will repeat--e.g., stick figures in certain body positions.  I'd like to be able to create a library of these image elements by drawing them or importing them as JPG/PNG/etc. and be able to select them and drag them from the library onto my main image.  I want to resize them as needed. Then I want to be able to select them later and move them around.  I also want to be able to combine elements to make a new element--for example, if I have a "hat" element and a "stick figure" element, then I want to be able to put the hat on the stick figure and add it to the library as a "stick figure wearing a hat" element.

What is this type of application called?

Comment: There are **many applications** which have the ability to store and use a Library of items. You'll need to be more descriptive about the nature of the art and it's creation and delivery. Off-hand, Adobe Illustrator and it's symbol's panel would work. However, not for JPG or PNG images. Then there are apps such as ToonBoom which are designed for animation (which it sort of sounds like you may be doing). -- What have you tried? why is it not sufficient?

Comment: @Scott, what do you mean by "nature of the art"?  It is  an image that has a lot of repeated design elements, and I want to be able to alter them universally, so if I add ears to the "hat" symbol, that change should carry over to the "stick figure wearing a hat" symbol, so now it's a "stick figure wearing a hat with ears".  I haven't tried anything yet (just freehand drawing), I just want to know what this "symbol-made-of-symbols" feature is called so that I can search for apps that have it and compare them.

Comment: If you are working with raster art (jpg, png, gif) the answers will be *drastically* different than if you are working with vector content. You need to spend some time actually thinking about output and input and how you want to create the art, as well as how you want to save/export the art. Those areas will completely alter any answers. While random "google this for me" is okay in some instances, you should have a clear idea about what you need or want to do. Chances are, yes, there's software to do what you want. But currently, no one here can *really* understand what that may be.

Comment: @Scott, I want to draw some vector objects using primitives.  Then I want to create groups of these vector objects that are themselves vector objects, groups of groups, and so on.  I want to be able to modify an object and have its results reflected in all instances of that object--I've read that I can do this with a Smart Object in Photoshop.  Once I have the massive composite vector object that comprises the entire image, I want to export the results to a JPG or print the object on an arbitrarily large sheet of paper.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to draw some vector objects using primitives.

Adobe Illustrator

> Then I want to create groups of these vector objects that are themselves vector objects, groups of groups, and so on. I want to be able to modify an object and have its results reflected in all instances of that object

Adobe Illustrator Symbols

> I've read that I can do this with a Smart Object in Photoshop.

Forget Photoshop if you are working with vector primitives. You may as well stick to Illustrator. Photoshop offers **no** benefit based on the above comments.

> Once I have the massive composite vector object that comprises the entire image, I want to export the results to a JPG or print the object on an arbitrarily large sheet of paper.

Again, Adobe Illustrator.

There amy be other software which will do all this. The basics are simply a **vector** editing application which has a feature similar to Adobe Illustrator Symbols.

Comment: It looks like I'll be able to use cloning in Inkscape to do this.  I'll give that a try and see if I can get it done without needing to purchase Illustrator.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with Inkscape, but it is vector in nature which is a plus and should allow manipulation of pieces with degradation.

Comment: errr. I meant **without** degradation.

Answer (score 0):

Most any drawing application will work. Given that you want to resize things, you likely want a vector tool such as Adobe Illustrator or Inkscape. As for creating a library, the simplest solution is to just have all your objects sitting to the side of your workspace and cut and paste them as needed.